# Run unit test when saving file in PhpStorm

Tags: php, unit-testing, automation, phpunit, phpstorm

I have set up PhpStorm 5 with PHPUnit, and I'm curious if PhpStorm might have some functionality that will automatically run a unit test when saving a file. Like watchr and guard. I have tried search our beloved www and the PhpStorm docs, but haven't been able to find a solution for it.

Comment: PhpStorm has no such ability (to execute something when file gets saved). You can **try** recording a **macro** to 1) save file and 2) run unit test .. and then assign it some shortcut and use it instead of saving (obviously, if file gets saved automatically, this macro is not getting involved). Other than that -- look for some external file watcher that can execute specific actions on file modification. **P.S.** This is the ticket that asks for similar kind of functionality: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85791

Comment: Thanks for a very clear answer @LazyOne. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 26):

As of version 6, PHPStorm has "File Watchers"

- Open your project preferences.
- Select File Watchers from the left hand list of options.
- Click the + symbol at the bottom of the empty right hand panel.
- Select `<custom>`

You will have to set up a command line for PHPUnit, it wont be the integrated testing, but you can have errors output to the console (which is good a good start!)

Various macro options are available to you, so you can include (for example) `$FileNameWithoutExtension$Test.php` in the arguments passed to your command line.

I personally had to set up two watchers. The first detected modifications to project files, and the second detected changes to test files (the second did not append `Test.php` to the filename) I also created a new project scope to exclude the tests directories from the first watcher.

You may also want to turn off immediate synchronisation, as this causes PHPUnit to run when PHPStorm auto-saves files.

My other settings are like:

- File Type: `PHP files (PHP)`
- Scope: `Project excluding tests`
- Program: `/path/to/php`
- Arguments: `/path/to/phpunit --configuration /path/to/phpunit.xml.dist /path/to/tests/$FileNameWithoutExtension$Test.php`
- Working directory: `$FileDir$`
- Output paths: `$FileDir$`

No output filters set, syntax error checks enabled, and console showing errors.

Comment: Sorry for late response, but this is great info! I have already upgraded :) Thanks a lot for coming back to this question Leigh

Comment: Great answer! Just followed the steps above and I made it work. Setting have changed a bit for PHPStorm 7 though, so here's an image with the details I've used to make it work:
**[link to GDocs](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1mk2abn6k4cxa3HhqviVcshiwww3EvFkX_VhBtjXN3FE/edit)**
. I've also create my own scope in PHPStorm Settings where I've included the files I want to be "watched"

Comment: You can use phpunit's `--filter` option to simplify your config & just have 1 watcher. Just change the Arguments setting to be `--filter $FileNameWithoutExtension$` and is will execute the test regardless of wether you edit the file or unit tests.

Comment: Nice tip, thanks @StuartGrimshaw. One day I'll have to revisit and edit this.

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit watcher named as hot phpunit runner

https://github.com/slavahatnuke/hot-phpunit-runner

Answer (score 2):

In 2017 Jetbrains release a feature that allow auto-run for tests.
It's located in the `Run` console, therefore it's linked to the run settings, easing the setup of this autorun.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/07/autorun-phpunit-tests-in-phpstorm-2017-2/

Comment: In more recent versions of the IDE (2023 and up), there's also a new icon in toolbar in the Run tool window that can enable/disable this functionality. It looks like the "Rerun" icon (a circular arrow with a green triangle), but it's labeled "Rerun Automatically" and contains *two* arrows which form a circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at [TDDRunner](https://github.com/Scyks/TDDRunner)

It is console tool that execute PHPUnit autmaticly on file changes. You can also configure PHPUnit by excuting only one file ot whatever.

```
/usr/bin/tddrunner --group=test
```

There's a a [German article](http://blog.secu-ring.de/software/call-again-phpunit-test-driven-development-watcher/) providing further detail.